# Tools for fast aggregation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, aggregation, delta

I'm looking for a solution to aggregate data quickly with a regular delta load of any updates to the transactional database.

We currently have the transactional DB and then a read-only replica, which is being used for our reporting, by changing the connection string to read-only application intent. This isn't ideal as we have to aggregate on the fly with SQL queries and we also can't index separately to support the read-only queries.

In our old application we used to use CDC with a DW and SSAS cube, however, after moving to Azure the multideimensional cube is not supported. I have been looking at the possibility of Azure Sync to replicate the data to a second repository and then using databricks for the aggregation. I'm not sure if this is the right approach as I would then need to pass the aggregated data back to the reporting repository (whatever I decide it's going to be). I don't want to have to split the raw and aggregated data and ideally want a single data source for all of it.

I'm sure this is a common design challenge, so I would like to know

a) What are the best tools in Azure for replication / delta loads to a second repository?

b) What is the best tool for aggregating data quickly?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't *ask* anything.

Comment: What tools do people use for replication and aggregation in Azure?

Comment: Then your question is off-topic; tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic here (as the [tour] tells you, which you failed to read after prompted to).